# What is this Google Maps scroll animation called and how do I replicate it?

Tags: android, animation, layout, material-design

I want to implement a similar design to this, where I have an image on top and the detailed information below, and I can move the information up and do a little animation of hiding/showing stuff once the image is totally covered.

I have no idea how this is called, therefore no idea where to start looking.

[image].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Collapsing Toolbar](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/). There are all kinds of code samples online for this and scrolling behavior, but this link should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can replicate it using [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout). Here's a good [tutorial](https://medium.com/@martinomburajr/android-design-coordinator-layout-1-an-introduction-10a1b91ded28) on it and here's [another](https://android.jlelse.eu/coordinatorlayout-basic-8040c74cf426).

It's useful for coordinating the views that are inside it - aka how each view interacts with the other, you can add a collapsing toolbar and some scrollviews inside the parent CoordinatorLayout.